# CentOS 7 can not start

Tags: linux, centos

I have CentOS 7. CentOS can not start.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `initrd` has problem. you should attention about all these :

> 1.you have no initrd on /boot.
>
> 2.your `bootloader` dose not have any line to describe initrd to run kernel on ram.
>
> 3.maybe your file systems have some thing wrong. make sure about MBR, bootfs(/boot).

Comment: You should start it in rescue mode and try to edit SELinux Policy from Permissive to Enforcing